# fsck + why fsck insist to not use "-a" flag?

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, fsck

Recently we get a lot of kernel messages on our RHEL VM server as:

```
[Mon Oct  4 11:33:32 2021] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): htree_dirblock_to_tree:914: inode #397095: block 1585151: comm du: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0(4096), inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0
```

so we derided too run `fsck` automatically with `-a` option ( after `umount` of course  )

```
$ fsck -a /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
/dev/sdb contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sdb: Directory inode 397095, block #1, offset 0: directory corrupted


/dev/sdb: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
```

in spite we declare to use the `-a` option , `fsck` insist to not use it

So the last option is to do it manually as

```
#  fsck  /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdb contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Inode 2134692 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix<y>? yes
Unattached inode 2134798
Connect to /lost+found<y>? yes
Inode 2134798 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix<y>? yes
Unattached inode 2135050
Connect to /lost+found<y>? yes
Inode 2135050 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix<y>? yes
Unattached inode 2135058
Connect to /lost+found<y>? yes
Inode 2135058 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix<y>? yes
```

and as we can see above it takes time

Any idea how to force `fsck` to use `-a` flag or to run `fsck` without manual steps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-a` (or `-p`) option is used to tell `fsck` to try to fix the filesystem without user interaction, if this is not possible (there is a risk of losing data or further corrupting the filesystem by choosing a wrong option) `fsck -a` will fail and tell you to run it in manual mode and decide yourself how each error should be fixed.

From [e2fsck man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2fsck.8.html):

> Automatically repair ("preen") the file system.  This option will cause e2fsck to automatically fix any filesystem  problems that can be safely fixed without human intervention.  If e2fsck discovers a problem which may require the system ad‐
> ministrator to take additional corrective action, e2fsck will print a description of the problem and then exit  with  the
> value  4  logically or'ed into the exit code.  (See the EXIT CODE section.)  This option is normally used by the system's
> boot scripts.

If you want to run `fsck` completely non-interactively you can use the `-y` option to answer `yes` to all question but I would advice against doing that.

Comment: Could be added that `-p` is preferred over `-a`: `-a     This option does the same thing as the -p option.  It is provided for backwards compatibility only; it is suggested that people use -p option whenever possible.
`